# Required List parameter 'ids' is not present

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am testing a controller and ran into a problem that I cannot solve.
I can’t understand why it requires IDs and where it is lacking.

Here is my controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ads/in/rubrics")
    public List<Ad> findAllAdInRubricByIds(@RequestParam(value = "ids", required = true) List<Integer> ids) {
        return adService.findAllAdInRubricByIds(ids);
    }
```

test method

```
@Test
    public void findAllAdInRubricByIds() throws Exception {

        List<Ad> ads = new ArrayList<>();
        ads.add(initAd());

        Mockito.when(controller.findAllAdInRubricByIds(((ArgumentMatchers.anyList())))).thenReturn(ads);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/ad/ads/in/rubrics"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(0));

    }
```

Error

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = Required List parameter 'ids' is not present
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in error - Required List parameter 'ids' is not present, add ids in request param as below:

```
mockMvc.perform(
            get("/ad/ads/in/rubrics?ids=1,2,3"))
```